# how do I check the encoding of a file in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, encoding, character-encoding

How can I check whether a file is encoded in UTF-8, ANSI, etc... in visual studio 2010?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Found out that if you go to "File" and then click on "Advance Saved Option" it displays the currently opened file's encoding. Hope this helps some people.

Comment: This works perfectly fine in VS 2013 as well, My 2cents: If you are using source control, and you change the encoding, you won't be able to diff between files!

Comment: @Narvalex you probably found it by now as your question is a few months old, but in VS 2017, if you select File -> Save [filename] As..., you click the small down arrow on the Save button, and there is an option to Save With Encoding that will indicate the current encoding

Answer (score 7):

Or locate the file in source explorer and open it's properties Dialog from the context menu.