# utf-8 error in partial class

Tags: c#, utf-8

In my form application, I create a partial class of the form like designer to reduce complexity of code with categorizing the methods (I could use different classes but it's not possible at this point).

I have a `string` value that contains several utf-8 characters.

`string t = "şçıer";`

if I declare this `string` in partial form that I created, when I try to pop up a message box to show this `string` something go wrong.

Result:  `þçýer`

But it's okay when I declare it in form1.cs

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416946/how-do-i-check-the-encoding-of-a-file-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encoding mismatch.

**0xfe** is **ş** in Latin-5, and **þ** in Latin-1, Latin-6, Latin-9, and CP-1252.

**0xfd** is **ı** in Latin-5, and **ý** in Latin-1, Latin-6, Latin-9, and CP-1252.

**ş** in UTF-8 would be 0xc5 0x9f, and **ı** would be 0xc4 0xb1.

So some part in your chain is either *in* the wrong encoding, or *declaring* the wrong encoding. Make sure you are actually *using* UTF-8 throughout, because evidence suggests you are using Latin-5 (ISO-8859-9) in your source, and interpreting it as Latin-1 (or one of the other encodings mentioned above).

Comment: Shameless plug: Since I am working with encodings on a daily basis, I created [a table putting the various ISO and most common CP encodings side by side](http://www.rootdirectory.de/chrome/site/encoding.html), which makes checking for mismatches like this one really simple.